# How do I add this OnClick event script to a custom button I’ve created?

Tags: php, scripts, events

I’ll start by saying (and it will probably be obvious) that I’m not very experienced in html or php coding. I’m learning some things as I’m creating this website, but I’m stumped with this one.

I’m trying to take an onclick event script that pops up an iframe type rewards plugin interface, I just don’t like the constant pop up option they have. So they gave me this script to use in a custom button, but I don’t know how to make that happen:

GRWidgetObj.showPopup();

Do I just add it in to my buttons “url” section? Again... I’m not very familiar with this type of thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Did they give you any documentation or examples? I would ask if they have any, it seems pretty poor to just send you a little piece of script and not tell you where to put it.

Comment: No they didn’t. They sent this first: <div style="text-align: left;"><a class="ec-widget" href="https://gratisfaction.appsmav.com/contest/referral/bgqc" rel="nofollow"> </a></div>.       But I’m pretty sure that was just the embedded code to get their pop up to show up. They just said use the script to trigger the code in my custom button. I did send them a reply asking exactly what to do with it! ‍♂️

Comment: Have you tried `<button onclick="GRWidgetObj.showPopup();">Click</button>` or `<a href="#" onclick="GRWidgetObj.showPopup();">Click</a>` if the page already includes a script which defines the `GRWidgetObj` object ?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much